# Cannot get log records in Loki

Tags: grafana, amazon-ecs, fluentd, grafana-loki

I have created ECS cluster according to [this doc](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/aws/ecs/)

I was using CloudFormation template:

```yaml
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Resources:
      # ...
      TaskDefinition:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
          Family: !Sub "${Application}-${Env}"
          ExecutionRoleArn:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "${Env}-TaskExecutionRole"
          Cpu: 256
          Memory: 256
          ContainerDefinitions:
            - Name: nextjs
              Image: nextjs
              DependsOn:
                - containerName: log_router
                  condition: START
              Essential: true
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awsfirelens
                Options:
                  Name: loki
                  Url: "http://loki.xxx.com/loki/api/v1/push"
                  Labels: "{job=\"firelens\"}"
                  RemoveKeys: "container_id,ecs_task_arn"
                  LabelKeys: "container_name,ecs_task_definition,source,ecs_cluster"
                  LineFormat: key_value
              Links:
                - log_router
            - Name: nginx
              Image: nginx
              DependsOn:
                - containerName: nextjs
                  condition: START
              Essential: true
              PortMappings:
                - ContainerPort: 80
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awsfirelens
                Options:
                  Name: loki
                  Url: "http://loki.xxx.com/loki/api/v1/push"
                  Labels: "{job=\"firelens\"}"
                  RemoveKeys: "container_id,ecs_task_arn"
                  LabelKeys: "container_name,ecs_task_definition,source,ecs_cluster"
                  LineFormat: key_value
              Links:
                - nextjs
                - log_router
            - Name: log_router
              Image: grafana/fluent-bit-plugin-loki:latest
              Essential: true
              FirelensConfiguration:
                Type: fluentbit
                Options:
                  enable-ecs-log-metadata: true
              LogConfiguration:
                LogDriver: awslogs
                Options:
                  awslogs-group: firelens-container
                  awslogs-region: us-east-1
                  awslogs-create-group: true
                  awslogs-stream-prefix: firelens
              memoryReservation: 50
```

All three containers are started and running, but I'm getting this error message in CloudWatch:

> Output plugin 'loki' cannot be loaded

The screenshot (sorry, but it is failing when I add it as an image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBqvp.jpg

And Grafana Loki is empty

Where is the mistake? Could it be related to `DependsOn` or `Links`?

Answer (score 1):

Struggled from the same issue. Turns out, the docs are wrong. The plugin's name is "grafana-loki", not just "loki" as stated in the docs. Maybe this changed some time and the docs are just outdated.

```
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
    "options": {
        "Name": "grafana-loki",
        "Url": "https://[...]/loki/api/v1/push",
        "Labels": "{job=\"firelens\"}",
        "RemoveKeys": "container_id,ecs_task_arn",
        "LabelKeys": "container_name,ecs_task_definition,source,ecs_cluster",
        "LineFormat": "key_value"
    }
},
```

Comment: If you follow the docs closely, you'll see that the logConfiguration stanza gets converted into a Fluentbit configuration and that one in turn uses "grafana-loki" as Name, not just "loki": https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/fluentbit/